# Why is this while statement looping infinitely?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, while-loop

I am using Python 2.7 in Windows PowerShell.

```
def loop(loop):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    while i < loop:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i += 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i



value = raw_input("Choose the loop value:\n>")
print value
loop(value)
```

When I enter `6` as the input for `value`, `loop()` turns into an infinite loop.

Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: change `while i < loop:` to `while i < int(loop):`.

Comment: Are you sure? When I run it, it is finite.

Comment: Style/syntax pointer: while it's necessary in other languages, you rarely, if ever, want to explicitly declare a variable just to keep track of loop count.  Use `for i in xrange` instead.  As a bonus, it would be instantly clear that you weren't giving `xrange` an int.

Answer (score 4):

The result of your `raw_input`, the variable `value` (passed to `loop` in your function) is a string. You are comparing this to `i`, an integer. In Python 2.x, all integers are less than all strings, so `i < loop` is always true no matter how big `i` gets.

Convert your input to an integer to make the comparison work:

```
value = int(raw_input("Choose the loop value:\n>"))
```

(And I'd also suggest not naming your function's argument the same as the function itself; it's just confusing.)

Comment: @CTZhu 'Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.'

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `raw_input` in `int()`.

replace:

```
 value = raw_input("Choose the loop value:\n>")
```

on:

```
 value = int(raw_input("Choose the loop value:\n>"))
```

OR you can just change:

```
while i < loop:
```

to

```
while i < int(loop):
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are actually running loop('6') rather than loop(6).

Answer (score 0):

because value is a string

you should call your function like this

```
loop(int(value))
```